# Cannot sort Java Set using Comparator.Comparing

Tags: java, set

I am trying to sort a Java Set using Comparator.comparing.

I have already tried the following

```
Set<Survey> sortedSet = surveySet.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Survey::getCreatedDate).reversed()).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

It returns the same sort without sorting by createdDate (as most recent). What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**

Just providing an update how I actually solved my question with a work around.

Converted the set to List and then applied Comparator.comparing on the List which worked.

```
List<Survey> sortedSurveyList = surveySet.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

Collections.sort(sortedSurveyList,(Comparator.comparing(Survey::getCreatedDate).reversed()));
    return  sortedSurveyList;
```

Nevertheless, this is not the answer I am looking for. I am wondering why Comparator.comparing did not work for the Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a `Set`, which has no order. Try using a collection that has an order, such as `SortedSet` (implementation: `TreeSet`) or a `List`.

```
final Set<Survey> surveySet = null;
final List<Survey> sortedList = surveySet.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Survey::getCreatedDate).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

final SortedSet<Survey> sortedSet = surveySet.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
                    () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Survey::getCreatedDate).reversed())));
```

Answer (score 4):

Per the documentation on [`Collectors#toSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--)

> Returns a Collector that accumulates the input elements into a new Set. There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned; if more control over the returned Set is required, use toCollection(Supplier).
>
> This is an unordered Collector.

So ordering and then collecting using that collector doesn't make sense. You'd have to instead use `Collectors.toCollection(Supplier)`, providing a set which guarantees ordering, like a `LinkedHashSet`.